# Running chrome extension process while popup is closed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Basically I am trying to create an Auto Visitor Extension for Chrome to open a website's URL after some specific time. When I open the popup everything works fine but when the popup is close nothing works. I am trying to find out a method to run that Auto Visitor Extension even when the popup is close I have read multiple questions regarding this phenomena on Stack Overflow but none of them clarifies what I am looking for.

Here is my manifest file:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Auto Visitor",
  "description": "This extension will visit multiple pages you saved in extension",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions": [
   "activeTab",
   "storage",
   "tabs",
   "http://*/",
   "https://*/"
   ]
}
```

The background file that i want to run even when popup is close :

**background.js**

```
// this will work only when you denie the background script in manifest
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details) {
    var initTime = 5;
    chrome.storage.local.set({"avtime": initTime}, function() {});
});
reloadMainTab();
function reloadMainTab() {
 chrome.storage.local.get('avurl', function (result) {
      var urlsToLoad = result.avurl;
      console.log(urlsToLoad);
      if(urlsToLoad==undefined){
        // do nothing
      }else{
          var urlsArr = urlsToLoad.split(",");
              chrome.storage.local.get('avtime', function (result) {
                  var thisTime = result.avtime;
                  /*
                   setting it to -1 because it gets incremented by 1 
                   when it goes into getSelected method
                  */
                  var index=-1;
                  setInterval(function(){
                    if(index < urlsArr.length-1){ 
                      chrome.tabs.getSelected(function (tab) {
                        // console.log('index in get selected'+index)
                        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id,{url: urlsArr[index]});
                      });
                      index++;
                    }else{
                      index=-1;
                    }  
                  }, thisTime+"000");

              });
      }
  });
}
```

any help would be really appreciated

Comment: You're using an event page which unloads after 5 seconds of inactivity and restarts on activity (losing all js timers and variables, of course). The easiest "solution" is to use `"persistent": true`, but it's lame, so a better solution is to switch to chrome.alarms API instead of setInterval.

Comment: Hey @wOxxOm thank you for replying i tried setting `"persistent": true` but didn't work out let me check `chrome.alarms` API

Comment: When you change manifest.json you need to reload the extension on chrome://extensions page.

Comment: Let me try one more time.

Comment: yeah its working fine now but its reloading all tabs which ever i visit can i just restrict it to one tab only?